# Evaluation of the limit by using epsilon-M approach.

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x + \sin x}{3x + 1}$$

How do we evaluate the limit of this equation? If the numerator is just $\sin x$, it is easy just to assume it to be 1. In this case, can we just assume it to be $x+1$ for the numerator?

Comment: If by "assume" you mean "being bounded by", then: yes for $x\to+\infty$, but it should be $-x-1$ for $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show that the limit of interest is $1/3$ using an "$\epsilon-M$" proof we proceed as follows.

For any given $\epsilon>0$,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x+\sin(x)}{3x+1}-\frac13\right|&=\left|\frac{3\sin(x)-1}{3(3x+1)}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{4}{9x}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $x>M=\frac{4}{9\epsilon}$.  And we are done!

Comment: I would highlight the key steps taken here: (1) Guess the limit (in any way whatsoever). (2) Compute the difference between the expression and the limit. (3) Simplify and estimate the difference if possible and necessary. (4) See if an $\epsilon$-$M$-relationship suggests itself.

Comment: @joonasilmavirta This was originally intended as a hint only, and then expanded to provide a complete solution.  It is not intended to be a lesson on "how" to tackle a problem of this nature.

Comment: How did u find 4/9x?

Comment: @JonSirNo  $|3\sin(x)-1|\le 3|\sin(x)|+1\le 4$ and $|3(3x+1)|\ge 9x$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 10):

Hint:

When $x>0$,

$$\frac{x-1}{3x+1}\le \frac{x+\sin x}{3x+1}\le \frac{x+1}{3x+1}$$

Comment: is it possible to use the squeeze theorem for this case?

Comment: It works, as $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-1}{3x+1}= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{3x+1}$

Comment: This isn't quite an $\epsilon-M$ proof.

Comment: Yes, this is just a hint. I suppose it is easier to work on rational functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$$ you can write: $$\frac{x-1}{3x +1}\leq \frac{x +\sin(x)}{3x +1}\leq \frac{x+1}{3x+1}.$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: so, can I apply it for the epsilon-M approach?

Comment: You're missing the lower bound... else this is inconclusive.